# For set type, why would we need both discard() and remove() function?

Tags: python

```
set.remove(x) : delete x from set, if x doesn't exist, KeyError raised up.

set.discard(x) :  delete x if x in set
```

Why we need these two functions at the same time?

If they are necessary, why list function does only have remove()?

Comment: Because the second does not raise an exception?

Comment: I know that, and I know some people would answer this, people are good at explaining existing things, so I post an additional question at the end of the question.

Comment: Sometimes you *need* the error raising behaviour, sometimes you want to remove elements without raising an exeption. `list.remove()` is a different beast because lists can have *multiple occurences* of an element. You need to compare `set` with `dict` instead.

Comment: @MartijnPieters， suddenly I understood! Is it because list can be nested like [{1:2},{3:4, 5:[6,7,{8:9}]}] which the situation dealing with delete its element is quite different with set. So things are different! I think your comment is the best answer for this question.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, And I found set is an unordered list! Wow~

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the situtation, you might need to either check whether a deletion was successful or simply attempt to delete something without needing confirmation.

Therefore, for these different cases, the two methods are provided for flexibility for the user.

For example, if you simply wanted to remove all number in a set that were below 10, you could simply call `set.discard(x)`

However, if you wanted to delete something from a set and know whether it was actually in the set in the first place, you would use `set.remove(x)`

For your question about why `lists` don't have `discard()`, it is simply a matter of implementation, the two types, `sets` and `lists` might have been created to serve different purposes. Also, you can easily perform the `discard()` in `lists` as follows:

```
try:
    list.remove(x)
except ValueError:
    pass
```

Comment: So, why list object has no discard() function?

Comment: The rationale for discard/remove should be look for in the corresponding PEP: http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0218/, but in this case, they don't mention it.